# pass the value of variable as error log in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, error-log

I tried to print the value of variable in php error logs file by using the function error_log() in xampp. It is not printing the value in error logs.

Comment: Well then you probably did something wrong. But because you failed to show us any relevant code, we can hardly tell you what that might be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask